# Lag 0 is not plotted in GGCcf

Tags: r, ggplot2, lag

With the following code I plotted the Cross Correlation of my data. All works wonderful, however the visualization does not depict Lag 0, which is highly important for my studies.

```
p= ggCcf(
  df_ccf$Asia_Co,
  df_ccf$EU_USA,
  lag.max = 10,
  type = c("correlation", "covariance"),
  plot = TRUE,
  na.action = na.contiguous)
  
plot(p)
```

The plot is looking like that:

[image: ccf plot]

Head of data:

[image: Image of Data]

Comment: Would you provide a head of your data to check!

Comment: thanks for your quick answer :) The two Data rows contain percentage values


EU_USA Asia_Co
1.004125933 1.01078592
1.038617134 1.028931428
1.04106565 1.010987618
1.024893137 0.99162369
1.004075708 0.990436767
0.997520044 1.010836195
1.021801838 1.056269411
0.964128553 0.973540813
0.976369063 0.993902511

Comment: Thank you. Please see here: <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example> to get good support for the future. It is essential to have a Minimal, Reproducible Example to provide adequate support.

Comment: thank you for the advice, i will stick to that in the future :)

Comment: so are you able to help me TarJae?

Comment: Sorry but I can't reproduce your plot.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue; it might be an issue/bug with 'ggCcf' from the forecast library. I couldn't get ggCcf to work, no matter what I tried. Anyone who wants to reproduce this behaviour, try:

```
ggCcf(c(1,2,3,4),c(2,3,4,6))
```

The workaround is using regular/base R ccf:

```
max_lag = 10
result = ccf(series1, series2, lag.max = max_lag)
y = results$acf
x = c(-max_lag:max_lag)
```

You can use these two series to plot the ccf using ggplot2 and choosing an appropriate ylim.

The downside of this all is less conveniance, but the upside is that you can add some flair/styling to your plot now that you are doing everything yourself anyway ;).